# Prolog :Make my predicate return all possible solutions

Tags: prolog

I found this problem in 99-problems in prolog online. There is a solution (has nothing to do with mine) and I was wondering why mine won't work. Or to be precise: it works but it finds only 1 solution instead of all of them. The problem is stated as such:
*a) In how many ways can a group of 9 people work in 3 disjoint subgroups of 2, 3 and 4 persons?*

```
member(X,[X]).
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|R]):- member(X,R).

append(X,[],X).
append([],X,X).
append([H|R], [A|B], [H|W]):- append(R,[A|B],W).

group234(G,G2,G3,G4):- length(G2,2),
                       length(G3,3),
                       length(G4,4),
                       member(X,G),
                       member(Y,G),
                       member(Z,G),
                       member(X,G2),
                       member(Y,G2),
                       member(Z,G3),
                       append(G2,G3,I),append(I,G4,G).
```

**q1: Is there a way to use length and append and member as I did and sole this succesfully or do I need to completely rewrite this?**
**q2: Why does this code produce only 1 solution? Prolog should search for many possible members, shouldn't it?** (Obviously , it should not , because the language knows better than I do . But to my understanding it should so why it does not?)

Comment: You are stating that G (the group with 9 people) is concatenation of I and G4, and I is the concatenation of G2 and G3, so you are stating that G is the concatenation of G2, G3 and G4 (in that order). Therefore you have already split G in a first group of 2, then a group of 3 and ends with a group of 4. There is only 1 solution for such ordered split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only `append/3` to define a predicate to **choose and remove** one person of a group:

```
choose(X, L1, L2) :-
    append(A, [X|B], L1),
    append(A, B, L2).
```

For example:

```
?- choose(X, [a,b,c], Rest).
X = a,
Rest = [b, c] ;
X = b,
Rest = [a, c] ;
X = c,
Rest = [a, b] ;
false.
```

Then, using this predicate, you can define `group234/4` as:

```
group234(G, [A,B], [C,D,E], G4):-
    choose(A, G,  G0),
    choose(B, G0, G1), A @< B,
    choose(C, G1, G2), 
    choose(D, G2, G3), C @< D,
    choose(E, G3, G4), D @< E.
```

Notice that you need condition `A @< B`, to **avoid permutations** (since both lists `[A,B]` and `[B,A]` represent the same group). Analogously, conditions `C @< D` and `D @< E` avoid permutations of the list `[C,D,E]`.

Example:

```
?- group234([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i], G2, G3, G4).
G2 = [a, b],
G3 = [c, d, e],
G4 = [f, g, h, i] ;
G2 = [a, b],
G3 = [c, d, f],
G4 = [e, g, h, i] ;
G2 = [a, b],
G3 = [c, d, g],
G4 = [e, f, h, i] ;
G2 = [a, b],
G3 = [c, d, h],
G4 = [e, f, g, i] 
...
```

Comment: do you know why my code produced only one solution?

Comment: It produces only one solution because subgoals ```append(G2,G3,I),append(I,G4,G)``` force elements in group G2, G3 and G4 to appear in the same relative positions they appear in G. Thus, for example, group G2 can only contain the first two persons of the group (in the same order they appear in G).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem formulation is rather ambiguous.
The (nice! +1) solution proposed by @slago relies on elements being sortable, but I think that the solution should be rather expressed working on the *positions* of the list. Here is their solution completed, expressed using library predicates:

```
%!  %%%%

group234(G, [A,B], [C,D,E], G4):-
    select(A, G,  G0),
    select(B, G0, G1), A @< B,
    select(C, G1, G2),
    select(D, G2, G3), C @< D,
    select(E, G3, G4), D @< E.

n_group234_slago(N) :-
    numlist(1,9,L),
    aggregate_all(count,group234(L,_,_,_),N).
```

and here is mine

```
take_ordered(L,[X],R) :-
    select(X,L,R).
take_ordered(L,[X|Xs],R) :-
    append(H,[X|T],L),
    take_ordered(T,Xs,J),
    append(H,J,R).

group234_cc(L,[A1,A2],[B1,B2,B3],[C1,C2,C3,C4]) :-
    take_ordered(L,[A1,A2],U),
    take_ordered(U,[B1,B2,B3],[C1,C2,C3,C4]).

n_group234_cc(N) :-
    numlist(1,9,L),
    aggregate_all(count,group234_cc(L,_A,_B,_C),N).
```

Both `n_group234_slago(N)`, `n_group234_cc(N)` return the correct number `N` requested.

*Edit*

I was not satisfied with take_ordered/3. Then, I tried to express it with a DCG:

```
take_ordered([],[]) --> [].
take_ordered([X|Xs],Ys) --> [X],
    take_ordered(Xs,Ys).
take_ordered(Xs,[Y|Ys]) --> [Y],
    take_ordered(Xs,Ys).

take_ordered(L,O,R) :-
    phrase(take_ordered(O,R),L).
```

and the efficiency gain is notable, halving the inference count.

*Edit*

The proposed solution `group3/4` by the 'P-99: Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems' site is a lot less efficient than the proposals by @slago and me you find here.

```
?- numlist(1,9,L),time(aggregate_all(count,group3(L,A,B,C),N)).
% 122,373 inferences, ...

?- time(n_group234_cc(N)).
% 7,549 inferences, ...
```

Comment: Prolog terms are totally ordered, according to the standard total ordering of terms. Thus, I don't think it's needed to use list positions to avoid permutations. Am I wrong?